# cast date with nvarchar not working in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       [Date_of_Receipt]
FROM RPT_VIEW_Receive
WHERE CAST([Date_of_Receipt] AS NVARCHAR) >= '12-12-2016'
ORDER BY [Date_of_Receipt];
SELECT DISTINCT
       [Date_of_Receipt]
FROM RPT_VIEW_Receive;
```

[image]

i have a view with name **RPT_VIEW_Receive**

in my view all date is greater than 2017 ,

but in my first query i want to show all records greater than 2016..but its not showing all records ,

what could be the issue???

Comment: What's the data type of `Date_of_Receipt`?

Comment: data type is  nvarchar(50)

Comment: That's the problem. Can you change column data type?

Comment: @uzi i have lot of records ,,so how i can chnage data type now..it will get error right?

Comment: Are all values in the same format as `dd/mm/yyyy`? What's your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be with the format of the date column `[Date_of_Receipt]`. 
We have to note that the date is in DD/MM/YYYY.

Try using `CONVERT` instead of `CAST`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       CONVERT(DATE,[Date_of_Receipt],103)
FROM RPT_VIEW_Receive
```

The last parameter for `CONVERT` is the format we are using for parsing. 
That should work.

Comment: You can look at the microsoft documentation on various datetime formats for more information on this.

Answer (score 1):

try this one.. Check the static date in second operand of where that you passed(12-12-2016)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       [Date_of_Receipt]
FROM RPT_VIEW_Receive
WHERE CAST([Date_of_Receipt] AS date) >=  CAST('12-12-2016' AS date)
ORDER BY [Date_of_Receipt];
SELECT DISTINCT
       [Date_of_Receipt]
FROM RPT_VIEW_Receive;
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: instead of date i given nvarchar,but getting same result

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this..Do not use casting in the where clause. It will hamper the performance. What is the data type of Date_of_Receipt ?

```
select distinct  [Date_of_Receipt] from RPT_VIEW_Receive  
where [Date_of_Receipt] >= '20170101'
order by [Date_of_Receipt]
```

Comment: still getting same result

Comment: data type of Date_of_Receipt  ? Also can you pls provide the DDL of your table and the insert script for us to see whats happening?

Comment: data type is nvarchar(50)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query If you have stored dates as `nvarchar(50)`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Date_of_Receipt]
FROM Table
WHERE Cast([Date_of_Receipt] AS DATE) >= '12/12/2016'
ORDER BY [Date_of_Receipt];
```

If dates are stored as `date` (which is recommended), you can simply do this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Date_of_Receipt]
FROM Table
WHERE [Date_of_Receipt] >= '12/12/2016'
ORDER BY [Date_of_Receipt];
```

Note: This will show all records greater than `11/12/2016`. If you want to show all record greater than 2016, use `01/01/2017` instead of `12/12/2016`.

Comment: while i am executing your first query getting error like this: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.